# natvis in vscode with gdb gives "Explicit refresh required for visualized expressions"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, natvis

vscode is meant to be able to pretty print custom objects if given a natvis file. I'm running linux and debugging with gdb.

The [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis) say:

> For gdb/lldb debugging ("type": "cppdbg"), a subset of the Natvis framework has been ported to the Visual Studio Code C/C++ extension and the code resides in the MIEngine shared component. If additional features that are not implemented are requested, please file an issue on the MIEngine GitHub page with details of what is missing.

I've created a simple natvis file based on the natvis page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="MyArray">
    <DisplayString>{{size={size}}}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">size</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>ptr</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

I've included a reference to this file in my `launch.json`:

```
"visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/file.natvis",
```

After launching the debugger and hovering over a variable I see "Explicit refresh required for visualized expressions". This was promising because it shows vscode has found the file, but it still isn't able to apply it for some reason. There are no natvis logs/errors in any of the vscode `OUTPUT`/`DEBUG CONSOLE` tabs.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? How can I get vscode+gdb to use my .natvis file?

Comment: How is your experience with natvis for gdb now? Mine was rather poor, opened an MIEngine issue : https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/issues/1368. That was 1Y ago, I failed to draw any MS attention to it so far.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me came from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/476#issuecomment-277827714):

> can you make sure you have the property "showDisplayString": true set in your launch.json?

Adding the following line in addition to `visualizerFile` suddenly made the .natvis definitions work.

```
"visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/file.natvis",
"showDisplayString": true, // <-- add this
```

FYI, I also  noticed that vscode passes `--interpreter=mi` to `gdb`, so there is some explicit `gdb` support for interacting with the [MIEngine](https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine) referenced by the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis).

Comment: Adding a tip: your natvis XML file has to be perfectly formatted otherwise you won't get an error message and it will simply not work. In my particular case a single newline preceding the opening XML tag failed silently without the visualization.